# ChildNode[0] returning a string, but when I attempt to eval it either breaks or gives back an undefined value

Tags: javascript, calculator, evaluate

I am working on a basic calculator using Javascript for a col assignment. Everything is functioning correctly so far, but when I attempt to evaluate the contents of the "display" I have made it either breaks or gives back an undefined value. This is the case even though when I check in the console.log and the "display" gives back a string containing everything that I need to evaluate. Any help would be appreciated.

Please find my code attached:

```
function setup() {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
    document.getElementById(i).onclick = handleInput;       
    document.getElementById("x").onclick = handleInput;
    document.getElementById("/").onclick = handleInput;
    document.getElementById(".").onclick = handleInput;
    document.getElementById("-").onclick = handleInput;
    document.getElementById("+").onclick = handleInput;

    var x;  
    document.getElementById("=").onclick = evaluateInput;

  }

}

function handleInput(e) {
  //document.getElementById("screen");
  var s;
  s = document.getElementById("display").childNodes[0]
  s.nodeValue += e.srcElement.childNodes[0].nodeValue ;
  console.log(e.srcElement.id); 
}

function evaluateInput(e) {
  //document.getElementById("screen");
  var s= document.getElementById("display").childNodes[0]
  console.log(e.srcElement.id);
  console.log eval((document.getElementById("display").childNodes[0]));
}
```

Cheers...

Comment: Where exactly are you calling the `eval`?

Comment: I am attempting to call it inside of: console.log (document.getElementById("display").childNodes[0]);

Comment: But I have not been able to get it to work :-(

Comment: You're neither calling, nor *trying* to call, `eval()` anywhere in the code you've shown, which makes it incredibly difficult to offer any advice about what you're doing wrong (other than using `eval()` in the first place, obviously).

Comment: @DavidThomas: I have updated the code to show where I am trying to make use of eval. Any help you can offer would be appreciated.

Comment: A `childNode` (nor *any* node, so far as I'm aware) cannot be `eval()`'d, it only works on strings. So: have you tried: `console.log(eval(document.getElementById("display").childNodes[0].nodeValue));` (using `nodeValue` to get the string contained within the `node`, or you could use `textContent` or `innerText` in place of `nodeValue`).

Comment: @DavidThomas: The nodeValue has allowed the eval function display correctly in the console. Thanks a million!!!